# Can I use a single iPhone Developer Program account on more than one machine?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have three different development machines. Do I need three different iPhone Developer Program accounts or can I get one and use it on all three?

I see that it has to be activated... does this tie it to a machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [The Evil Boss' blog article](http://www.theevilboss.com/2009/06/iphone-sdk-development-on-multiple.html) you can use a single account on multiple machines for installing applications from those machines onto your iPhones/iPod/iPad devices without any issues. All you need to do is export the certificate from your primary machine's keychain and import it into the keychain of your additional machines.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe that you will need both the Worldwide Developer Certificate and the developer or distribution certificate for the all (that includes the device id for the relevant phone). You can download them from the iphone program portal at any time. ON a new machine you will probably have to request a certificate from an authority to get the ball rolling and sync up keychain correctly (having just had to do all of this after my hard drive crashed).